How to upload multiple images using multer, node.js and react.js
I am using multer to upload files in react.js. To upload a single i am using below code, it's working fine as you could see in the below screenshot.
How to upload multiple files using the same multer in react.js ?


backend node.js code:
const multer = require("multer");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'public/uploads/') 
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname)
  },
})

const upload = multer({ storage: storage })
   

app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), function (req, res) {
  res.json({})
})

frontend react.js code:
const [thumbImage, setThumbImage] = useState('')
const [thumbstatus, setThumbStatus] = useState('')


const handleThumbnail = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  let formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('file', thumbImage.data)    
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/upload', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
  })

  if (response) setThumbStatus("Thumbnail image uploaded.")

}



const handleThumbnailChange = (e) => {
  const img = {
    preview: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]),
    data: e.target.files[0],
  }
  setThumbImage(img)   
}


<div style={{margin:'100px'}}>

        <input type='file' name='file' onChange={handleThumbnailChange} />      
        <button onClick={handleThumbnail} type='submit'>Submit</button>
        
      {thumbstatus && <div className='text-success mt-2 mb-2'>{thumbstatus}</div>}

</div>


check out this question tread link
